# How to set-up Persistent Storage for eclipse-tomcat for backup and streaming (not using database)?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I am working on a Java Web-Application project using servlets, eclipse, and tomcat.

I would like to be able to dynamically store/create persistent files from servlets and allow the user to access the files using a link, without storing the files in the database.

I have read that getServletContext().getRealPath("/") is volatile and gets reset every time the server is restarted.

I have also read that creating a directory like "$HOME/.ourapp" would solve this. Although, I cannot seem to find how to set-up tomcat to allow the user to access the files using a link, using the eclipse-tomcat.

Question : How to set-up eclipse-tomcat so that the link to the website "http://localhost/" and the file "http://localhost/temp-xx.txt" is the same, while also allowing to dynamically create persistent data "temp-xx.txt" is generated by a servlet and allow the user to access it and does not get deleted when the server is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

This gets complicated, because Tomcat can server files using `DefaultServlet` (it just sends files back to the client, exactly as you'd expect from a web server), but it caches files internally, so modifying the file system underneath it can have some surprising behavior.

You can disable caching for the `DefaultServlet` but I've seen reports that it still behaves in surprising ways. The only fool-proof solution I've seen is to write your own servlet that streams the files from wherever they are stored.

But writing your own streaming servlet isn't as simple as you might think. If you want it to be high-performance, you'll want to enable all the nice HTTP features like range-requests, eTags, If-Modified-Since and all that stuff that the `DefaultServlet` already provides. Perhaps you should start with using the `DefaultServlet` and see how far it will get you.

The configuration is actually really easy: just add a `<Resources>` element to your `META-INF/context.xml` file and use a `postResources` attribute. You can find the documentation in the [Tomcat users' guide for resources](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/resources.html).